# How to perform a nested update using Ramda in the given object structure?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Assuming the follow object how is it possible to use Ramda to perform a nested update in a criteria given an application, criteria ID and data?

```
const application = {
  id: 'a1',
  features: [
    {
      id: 'f1',
      criterias: [
        { id: 'c1' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 'f2',
      criterias: [
        { id: 'c2' },
        { id: 'c3' }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The function would look something like this:

```
const updateCriteria = (application, criteriaId, data) => // magic...

updateCriteria(application, 'c2', { name: 'foo' })

// output: {
//  id: 'a1',
//  features: [
//    {
//      id: 'f1',
//      criterias: [
//        { id: 'c1' }
//      ]
//    },
//    {
//      id: 'f2',
//      criterias: [
//        { id: 'c2', name: 'foo' },
//        { id: 'c3' }
//      ]
//    }
//  ]
// }
```

Comment: https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens

Comment: what happens when you `updateCriteria(application, 'zzz', {})` where `zzz` is an unmatched criterion `id`?

Comment: user633183 thank for bring it to light, however, I'm interested to learn how to use Ramda to solve the happy path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lenses are probably your best bet for this.  Ramda has a generic [`lens`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens) function, and specific ones for an object property ([`lensProp`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp)), for an array index([`lensIndex`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensIndex)), and for a deeper path([`lensPath`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensPath)), but it does not include one to find a matching value in an array by id.  It's not hard to make our own, though.

A lens is made by passing two functions to `lens`: a getter which takes the object and returns the corresponding value, and a setter which takes the new value and the object and returns an updated version of the object.

Here we write `lensMatch` which find or sets the value in the array where a given property name matches the supplied value.  And `lensId` simply passes `'id'` to `lensMatch` to get back a function which will take an id value and return a lens.

Using any lens, we have the [`view`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#view), [`set`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#set), and [`over`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#over) functions which, respectively, get, set, and update the value.

We could use `idLens` like this:

```
const data = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'b'}, {id: 'c'}]

view (idLens ('b'), data) 
  //=> {id: 'b'}
set  (idLens ('b'), 'foo', data) 
  //=> [ {id: 'a'}, 'foo', {id: 'c'} ]
over (idLens ('b'), merge ({name: 'foo'}), data)
  //=> [ {id: 'a'}, {id: 'b', name: 'foo}, {id: 'c'} ]
```

So for your problem, we could write something like this:

```js
const lensMatch = (propName) => (key) => lens
  ( find ( propEq (propName, key) )
    , (val, arr, idx = findIndex (propEq (propName, key), arr)) =>
         update (idx > -1 ? idx : length (arr), val, arr)
    )

const lensId = lensMatch ('id')

const updateCriteria = (featureId, criteriaId, data, application) => over 
  ( compose 
      ( lensProp ('features')
      , lensId (featureId) 
      , lensProp ('criterias') 
      , lensId (criteriaId)
      )
    , merge (data)
    , application
    )

const application = {id: 'a1', features: [{id: 'f1', criterias: [{ id: 'c1' }]}, {id: 'f2', criterias: [{ id: 'c2' }, { id: 'c3' }]}]}

const newApp = updateCriteria ('f2', 'c2', {name: 'foo'}, application)

console.log(newApp)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>
const {lens, find, propEq, findIndex, update, length, view, set, over, compose, lensProp, merge} = R
</script>
```

But this presupposes that you know the `featureId`.  If you need to find both the `featureId` and the nested object with your internal id, you could write a more complex lens for that, but it will be much more heavyweight.

---

A minor note: 'criteria' is already plural, so 'criterias' is odd.  The singular is 'criterion'.

Comment: great primer for someone being introduced to topic of lenses

Comment: Scott, I did learned a lot of things in your answer. Thank you for that! I'll have to write a lens to find the feature ID as well to this complexity in only one layer. I'm aware of the trade-offs of scanning thru the application structure over and over again but right now I'm not worried about them now.