# Ramda lenses based on a some value in object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Community, hello . I stuck with a small issue.
I have such a data structure

```
{
    "type": "Shoes",
    "gender": "female",
    "userInfo": {
        "whois": {
            "male": {
                "htt": 20.2,
                "referenceBrands": [{
                    "category": "Shoes",
                    "size": 40
                }]
            },
            "female": {
                "height": 191.0,
                "age": 20,
                "referenceBrands": [{
                    "category": "Shoes",
                    "size": 35.5
                }, {
                  "category": "Apparel",
                  "size": 50
                }]
            }
        },
    }
}
```

I want to update a specific key in a reference brand based on `gender` and a `type` which are in a root.
Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805737/how-to-perform-a-nested-update-using-ramda-in-the-given-object-structure) (thanks to *Scott Sauyet*), I've created something like this. But as you see, I have hardcoded `gender` and `category` what the best way of using composition and point-free style to change this?

```
const lensMatch = (propName) => (key) => lens( 
   find(
      propEq(propName, key)
   ), 
   (val, arr, idx = findIndex(propEq (propName, key), arr)) =>
         update(idx > -1 ? idx : length (arr), val, arr)
   )

const lensCategory = lensMatch('category')
const genderLens = lensProp('gender')
const lensReferenceBrand = lensProp('referenceBrands')

const updateSize = (prop, value) => over(
  compose(
    lensPath(['userInfo', 'whois']),
    lensProp('female'),
    lensReferenceBrand,
    lensCategory('Shoes'),
    lensProp(prop),
  ), always(value), data)

updateSize('size', 100)
```

[Playground](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22Shoes%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22gender%22%3A%20%22female%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22userInfo%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22whois%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22male%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22htt%22%3A%2020.2%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22referenceBrands%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22category%22%3A%20%22Shoes%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A%2040%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22female%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22height%22%3A%20191.0%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22age%22%3A%2020%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22referenceBrands%22%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22category%22%3A%20%22Shoes%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A%2035.5%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22category%22%3A%20%22Footwear%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A%2035.5%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aconst%20lensMatch%20%3D%20%28propName%29%20%3D%3E%20%28key%29%20%3D%3E%20lens%0A%20%20%28%20find%20%28%20propEq%20%28propName%2C%20key%29%20%29%0A%20%20%20%20%2C%20%28val%2C%20arr%2C%20idx%20%3D%20findIndex%20%28propEq%20%28propName%2C%20key%29%2C%20arr%29%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20update%20%28idx%20%3E%20-1%20%3F%20idx%20%3A%20length%20%28arr%29%2C%20val%2C%20arr%29%0A%20%20%20%20%29%0A%0Aconst%20lensCategory%20%3D%20lensMatch%28%27category%27%29%0Aconst%20genderLens%20%3D%20lensProp%28%27gender%27%29%0Aconst%20lensReferenceBrand%20%3D%20lensProp%28%27referenceBrands%27%29%0A%0Aconst%20updateSize%20%3D%20%28prop%2C%20value%29%20%3D%3E%20over%28%0A%20%20compose%28%0A%20%20%20%20lensPath%28%5B%27userInfo%27%2C%20%27whois%27%5D%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20lensProp%28%27female%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20lensReferenceBrand%2C%0A%20%20%20%20lensCategory%28%27Shoes%27%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20lensProp%28prop%29%2C%0A%20%20%29%2C%20always%28value%29%2C%20data%29%0A%0AupdateSize%28%27size%27%2C%20100%29%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably write it something like this:

```js
const lensMatch = (propName) => (key) => 
  lens
    ( find (propEq (propName, key))
    , (val, arr, idx = findIndex (propEq (propName, key), arr)) =>
        update(idx > -1 ? idx : length (arr), val, arr)
    )

const updateSize = (prop, value, gender, category, data) => 
  set 
    ( compose 
        ( lensPath (['userInfo', 'whois', gender, 'referenceBrands'])
        , lensMatch ('category') (category)
        , lensProp (prop)
        )
    , value
    , data
    )
  

const data = {type: "Shoes", gender: "female", userInfo: {whois: {male: {htt: 20.2, referenceBrands: [{category: "Shoes", size: 40}]}, female: {height: 191, age: 20, referenceBrands: [{category: "Shoes", size: 35.5}, {category: "Apparel", size: 50}]}}}};

console .log (
  updateSize ('size', 100, 'female', 'Shoes', data)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {lens, find, findIndex, propEq, update, length, set, compose, lensPath, lensProp} = R  </script>
```

Note that I replaced `over` with `set`.  `over` is about creating a new value by applying a function to the old one, `set` simply sets it to the given value.  This means that I can drop the redundant `always` as well.

Of course you could also use

```
    ( compose 
        ( lensPath (['userInfo', 'whois'])
        , lensProp (gender)
        , lensProp ('referenceBrands')
        , lensMatch ('category') (category)
        , lensProp (prop)
        )
```

or even split that `lensPath` into two `lensProp`s, but I don't see a reason.

This is far from point-free.  In fact, the main function has five named parameters, two more than I'm generally comfortable with and four more than I prefer. But they all seem necessary.  And I only choose point-free when it improves readability.  I suspect that this would be made much worse by a point-free solution.

I don't know if any partially applied version of this would be helpful, but it would be easy enough to change the signature to

```js
const updateSize = (prop, value) => (gender, category) => (data) => ...
// ...
updateSize ('size', 100) ('female', 'Shoes') (data)
```

or some such, or to use `R.curry`.

Comment: Thank you, @ScottSauyet. Make sens